# Elastic beanstalk caching issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently using amazon elastic beanstalk. It seems when I alter fields in the json using http put/post/etc. the fields don't stay static and keep on altering from the most recent fields every time I refresh the page. For example, if I have a user email field that is set to null and then I add an email like example@gmail.com, every time I refresh the page it alters that email field from null to example@gmail.com (and continues alternating back and forth) instead of staying static. How could I prevent it from altering back and forth?

Comment: Could you go into more detail about "alter fields in the json using http put/post/etc". It's not clear what you are talking about here. Is this some function of your web application?

Comment: Yes, so when I go to a specific http url that I made like: http://blahblah.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/person and keep refreshing this page, the json fields alter back and forth if I keep refreshing it. So when I try to grab the data on an mobile device, it will sometimes give me the most updated values and sometimes it wouldn't.

Comment: Where is the data stored?

Comment: AWS RDS stores the information.

Comment: Are you caching the data at some point? Do you have multiple beanstalk servers behind an ELB?

Comment: Not that i am aware of. I just have one beanstalk application with a python file in it that connects to a few different classes. I believe it is a caching issue but not sure where the issue may lie. Are there some specific places I should look at? Could it be the way I set up beanstalk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112948/discussion-between-mitch94-and-mark-b).